# Validate in xCode Organizer results in "Unable to process app at this time due to a general error"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to validate my iPhone application using xcode and organizer. This is happening with xCode 6.0.1. I was able to validate my apps before with previous versions of xCode.

I'm getting the following error:

"iTunes Store operation failed."
Unable to process at this time due to a general error.

I have researched, and it seems like people had this problem before, I have tried solutions without luck, including the one listed below:

- a) Go into the certificates section in apples developer member center revoke ios development, revoke ios distribution from certificates section.
- b) Create new ios development and ios distribution certificates,
  download it, double click and that will be added into
  keychain. While creating the distribution one, I chose the App Store 
  and Ad Hoc.
- c) Delete distribution and development profiles and generate new
  ones based on the new certificates created in step (b). Download and double click on the new created certificates which will be added into xCode.
- d) In xCode, change the provisioning profile to the newly created
  ones from step (c).

Please let me know if I'm missing anything or if you have other suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why did you do any of those steps? Just try again. Apple's servers are simply being swamped with updates.

Comment: rmaddy - This is the fourth day this is happening. I wouldn't be asking the question if this was happening for only one or so day.

Comment: My point is that the error says it's a general error. The validation can't be processed at this time. Nothing about that message indicates that you need to redo your certificates and provisioning profiles.

Comment: As mentioned above, "I have researched, and it seems like people had this problem before, I have tried solutions without luck". It seems like certificates were the issue for people with the same problem. Hopefully someone else will come by and know what I could try other than **waiting**.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I got it to work, here is my resolution in case someone else runs into it:

- Created a new empty project and copied the files from "previous" project over. Validate and submit app now works.

Comment: While this may work; this is a very tedious thing to do in a large scale production app.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an Apple server issue! I was having the same issue over the last couple days, and it turns out that the provisioning profile I was using to validate the app had disappeared from the Member Center.

Go to https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action and make sure the provisioning profile you're trying to use is still there. If it's not, just create a new one, and update your build settings in Xcode to use the new profile. Make sure you also select the new profile when validating. This solved the problem for me!